# React-Native IOS Native Module Event Dispatching

Tags: ios, react-native

I have followed the tutorial too a T and my events don't seem to dispatch, but they do print what is in the functions. Here is my function I am trying to dispatch

Helper Class

```
#import "RCTBridge.h"
#import "RCTEventDispatcher.h"
- (void)loginEvent
{
  printf("Login Event");
  [self.bridge.eventDispatcher sendAppEventWithName:@"EventReminder"
                                               body:@{@"name": @"Type"}];
}
```

and I call it from my app delegate like this:

```
  Helper *helper = [[Helper alloc] init];
  [Helper loginEvent];
```

and listen like this

```
NativeAppEventEmitter.addListener('EventReminder', function(e: Event) {
    console.log(e);
  });
```

Comment: Did you add event listener in js side ?

Comment: Xeijp yes I did, I will edit my thing with code.